# How to resolve the signtool location from Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, continuous-integration

I'm setting up gitlab CI for windows that can be run on multiple windows machines, which means the EXACT path to `signtool.exe` may vary depending.  CI starts in powershell where signtool is not in the $path, as opposed to the Developer Powershell.

Is there a simple way to get to the latest signtool or run it through the Developer Powershell from the default powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the developer powershell as a step in the CI process to then call `signtool` directly from the command line.

in gitlab-ci.yml, it looked like the following

```
script:
  - '& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1"'
  - signtool sign <etc>
```

where my gitlab-runner is a shell executor where `shell=powershell`

Comment: I should also mention, since I spent a few hours debugging this, that there's a bug with loading the developer powershell like this.  It will strip any multi-line environment variables to just the first line.